# Setting up an Inter VLAN for new building

Tags: vlan, trunk, traffic-management

Have added a building to our existing motel business setup and looking to utilise a fibre trunk to share a single internet connection between an open guest network (LAN and WiFi to guest rooms) and our business network which will now reside in the new building.

Previously had two separate internet connections which effectively separated the business and guest networks and passed through a port based VLAN arrangement on Switch 1 to maintain the separation at the switch.

Guest internet access is managed through a RouterBoard RB433AH which separates the guest (eth3) and business (eth2) networks at the router however I am now looking to utilise a fibre trunk to the new building (Building 3) which is where I am now well out of my depth getting into VLAN tagging.

I assume the introduction of another managed switch means that they need to be statically addressed (currently OEM defaults), and to utilise the trunk would suggest tagging at the switch and router. I am looking for some help.

Internet access is fixed via NBN Modem in Building 1

Guest LAN and WAP’s need to pass straight through to Internet, no local LAN access. Managed via NAT on RB433 Router over eth3

All Network Management will be through VLAN 2 in Building 3

Both ALLOY GSS switches currently carry default IP address (192.168.1.1)

Ubiquiti UniFi PRO WAP to have two SSID’s – One for open Guest access (separate from business network and network management) and one for WPA2 protected VLAN 2 access [(Network Hardware)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtOsV.png)

Questions;
How do I address the switches?

```
e.g. Sw1 – 192.168.1.1
     Sw3 – 192.168.1.2
```

How do I set up packet tagging on the managed switches, router and Ubuquiti WAP to;

separate Guest and Business networks and;

enable network management and;

utilize the fibre trunk effectively?